# How can I create a type from just the properties of a class that has an extended class that isn't exported?

Tags: angular, typescript, types

Given I have this code:

```
class Arachnid {
    numberOfLegs: number = 8;
}
export class Spider extends Arachnid {
    numberOfEyes: number = 2;
}
```

How could I create a type from Spider that has just the numberOfEyes property?

I can't do:

```
type WolfSpider = Omit<Spider, keyof Arachnid>
```

because Arachnid is not exported. Is there a way to do this without the library author making changes?

Comment: Any news on this problem, William?

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible. TypeScript use [structural typing](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#what-is-structural-typing), which mean a type stores only its structure and not any information about class hierarchy. If the base class is not exported, there is no way to retrieve it.